# Is it ok to return a reference?

Tags: c++

I have something like

```
class X
{
    private:
    someclass obj;

    public:
    someclass& get()
    {
        return obj;
    }
};
```

I dont want to make obj public, so i get a reference of it and pass it around to functions.
Is this a good/ok practice or is it outright evil ?

Comment: Please Note: I am returing a reference because i want to modify it.

Comment: If you want to modify it, and you plan on exposing a straight reference, then what benefit do you foresee getting out of keeping it private?

Comment: Modifying is not the same as replacing. Calling code can't change the reference in `obj`, only the properties on it. Other code may depend on that reference not changing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you pass a non-const reference as in your code then `obj` can be modifed from outside your class. If you wish that it cannot be changed from outside `X` you must return a const ref,

```
const someclass& get();
```

Note with this case it is worth adding another const after the function name

```
const someclass& get() const;
```

which tells the compiler that calling `get()` on an `X` won't change its internal state. (This is not true of your example)

Answer (score 6):

It's not evil. It is how it is supposed to be done: you can return references to internal data members. You don't need to do it through pointers or by value if you don't want a copy: references were made to do this.

If you don't want it to be modified, you have to return a "const" reference to your internal data member:

```
public:
const someclass & get() const
{
    return obj;
}
```

Note that then I added const at the end of the get() method to instruct that using this method will not modify the class.

Comment: How will you ensure that your X stays around as long as obj is needed?

Comment: You have to ensure it yourself in your code, that you still can use it. You have to be careful about X lifespan

Comment: Using a shared_ptr is a better solution unless you can *prove* that the performance decrease is unacceptable.

Comment: I think obj should depend on X lifespan. If you put up code that takes a member of an object then discard this object away but keep a reference ( not a copy ) to one of its internal and use it, that's evil.

Comment: Exactly. But what can you do to enforce this? Just rely on carefulness?

Comment: In the general case I'd say yes, just rely on the user

Answer (score 5):

It is OK.

Just consider making the reference constant, or at least making two `get()` methods (one for normal and one for constant objects).

Answer (score 2):

What you did is technically correct: you get a reference to an internal part of X you use to change it.

The only thing you have to take care is that X itself lives longer than the place you store the returned reference.

There is nothing *evil* with this.

The evil thing is another: you allow full access to `obj` to whoever can cal `get()` (practically everyone). You are at all effect making public `obj` itself, giving the illusion it is still private.

If you accept everyone can modify obj... just make it public.
If you want "someone" can, keep it private an make *someone* a friend.
If you want anyone access `obj` in read-only ... return a const& fron a const function.

Answer (score 1):

Many books advice not to have direct access to variable and to use GET/SET methods like:

```
class SetandGet
{
public:
    void Set(int x){
        TheVariable = x;
    }
    int Get(){
        return TheVariable;
    }
private:
    int TheVariable;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I consider it evil. `obj` will be destroyed when the containing instance of `X` will be destroyed and you have no way to force callers of `X::get()` to take this into account:

```
someclass & evil() {
  X x;
  return x.get();
}
```

It *definitely* is evil ;-)

The only things that are safe to return by reference are either `*this` in a member function or arguments that were taken by reference in the first place.

If `obj` is small enough return it by value, otherwise implement some way of sharing its ownership. [Boost.SharedPtr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm), now part of the C++ standard, may be of help.

Comment: What you say is true also for pointers and is the same far whatever object is referring to another not in its control.
But if this is "evil" the most of dynamic data structure cannot exist!

Comment: Unless you are doing something odd with the internal variable, there is no real question as to the lifetime of the returned reference.  It has to be tied to *something*, after all.

Comment: @Emilio Garavaglia: Pointers have the slight advantage of at least being explicit about it, but they still leave the problem open. Obviously there's very little you can do without using dynamic memory, but if you want to write solid code you should adopt tools and techniques that enforce correct memory management. shared_ptr helps, and so does garbage collection.

Comment: @Dennis Zickefoose: Did you see the example I added? How can you ensure that nobody does anything similar?

Comment: Why consider a reference to `*this` a special case? Suppose `get()` returned `*this` by reference, then `X &evil() { X x; return x.get(); }` is just as bad as your evil function. Likewise, `int &evil() { std::vector<int> x(1); return x[0]; }` is bad, does that mean one should never use vector, because it does this thing you disapprove of? In all these cases, including your example, the problem lies with the person who wrote the function "evil", because they failed to consider the lifetime of the object to which they took a reference. As long as `get()` is properly documented, of course.

Comment: You can't.  But if your user does that, your user needs to figure out what language he's using, because this is a pretty common thing in C++.

Comment: @Nicola Musatti: Don't be "moralist". If I store a reference to something I didn't create or if I store a pointer to something I didn't create I run in the same problem: What I'm (de)referencing may go away without my knowledge, hence, I have to do that only temporarily and in an inner scope.
But that's my USER problem, not of the get() writer.
If I know C++ I must know scoping rules, and I have to assume my user also know them!

Comment: @Steve Jossop: I consider returning *this a special case because the caller is already in control of the lifetime of the returned object; in practice it's a special case of returning by reference an argument taken by reference. Obviously mine is an extreme example; still I consider it more likely that something similar is done in good faith than with your examples. As to std::vector, if I have to share objects I keep in a vector, I either pass them around by value or I use shared_ptr

Comment: @Emilio Garavaglia: One thing is what you do; another one is what you make available to others. Unless there are proven performance problems I consider being explicit about object ownership a big plus, not to be lightly forsaken.

Comment: "if I have to share objects I keep in a vector, I either pass them around by value or I use shared_ptr" - but `vector::operator[]` doesn't force you to do that. How come you're smarter than the questioner's users, such that you can respect the lifetime of the elements of your vector (so it's OK that `operator[]` returns a reference), but the users of this `get()` function can't respect the lifetime of what it returns (so it's evil for that to return a reference)? If you consider `vector` evil too, fine, I think everyone's point is just that your C++ style is very atypical.

Comment: vector needs to be as general as possible, which means that no performance sacrifice can be accepted. Is this true in general? I doubt it. vector is also extremely well documented: the standard, reference manuals, books, etc. Is this always the case for other code? I doubt it. I don't claim to be smarter than anybody else: I take responsibility for what my code does internally and I try to make the contracts I offer to my users explicit in the code itself. I stand by my claim that this is far better practice than not doing so; I'm well aware that there are situation where you cannot afford it.

Comment: @Nicola: "I consider being explicit about object ownership a big plus". Yes, I also can. But a reference is explicitly not ceasing an ownership. A pointer ... who knows? By my point of view, it is even more evil returning a pointer than a reference.

The point, however, is another: The "evilness" is subjective. Cannot be presented as "legal" or "moral" rule.

Comment: @Emilio Garavaglia: The OP used the term "evil". I just re-used his/her terminology. Apparently you missed my smiley...

Comment: By the way, I see that the downvoter is still anonymous. He/she should read better the StackExchange guidelines.